Compactness of $2^I$ without Tychonoff theorem
Let $I$ be the set of all atomic formulas and $2=\{ 0,1 \}$.
I want to prove the compactness of $2^I$ using Compactness theorem for propositional logic.
How do I prove this?(I recently studied the compactness theorem, so I don't know what to do.)

Since the compactness theorem is a consequence of Tychonov, you are asking whether the converse is true?

@GEdgar Yes. I’m asking whether the converse is true.

I closed as a duplicate - in the marked duplicate, I showed how to prove the full Tychonov Theorem from propositional compactness. Your case, restricted to $2^I$, is much simpler.

@AlexKruckman Thank you so much!

The compactness theorem is equivalent to the Boolean algebra prime ideal theorem, which is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice.  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/axiom-choice/

@GEdgar Right, I should have been more precise: in the duplicate I give a ZFC proof of Tychonov's Theorem using the compactness theorem as the main ingredient (but the proof also uses choice). In the case that the spaces are all Hausdorff (e.g. when they are all $2$), choice is not necessary, so we get a proof from the compactness theorem over ZF.
